# How to handle panic outside

Tags: go

Look at the following code snippet.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func explode() {
    // Cause a panic.
    panic("WRONG")
}

func recovery() int {
    explode()
    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("Try to handle panic")
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("FIX")
            fmt.Println("ERR", err)
        }
    }()
    fmt.Println("Print value")
    return 100

}

func main() {
    // Handle errors in defer func with recover.
    fmt.Println(recovery())
}
```

As you can see code above, I fired a panic in the explode function and want to handle it in the recovery function. But the panic does not get caught, I've got runtime error

```
goroutine 1 [running]:
main.explode()
        D:/gocode/src/samples/panic1.go:7 +0x6b
main.recovery(0xc082002250)
        D:/gocode/src/samples/panic1.go:18 +0x26
main.main()
        D:/gocode/src/samples/panic1.go:27 +0x26

goroutine 2 [runnable]:
runtime.forcegchelper()
        c:/go/src/runtime/proc.go:90
runtime.goexit()
        c:/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1

goroutine 3 [runnable]:
runtime.bgsweep()
        c:/go/src/runtime/mgc0.go:82
runtime.goexit()
        c:/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1

goroutine 4 [runnable]:
runtime.runfinq()
        c:/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:712
runtime.goexit()
        c:/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1
exit status 2
```

How to catch the panic in the recory function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call `explode()` first, the function that would handle the `panic` and try to recover is not yet registered (and never will be because you call `panic` inside `explode()`), so it won't be called and obviously it can't do its work.

You have to call `defer` first and then the `explode()` function:

```
defer func() {
    // recover() here, Your code omitted
}()
explode()
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/po5k7hBYnU).

Comment: Fist of all, thanks very much. It is wrong to use panic, instead of `if err != nil` statement?

Comment: @zero_coding `panic` and `recover` have their uses, but they should be used only in _exceptional_ cases. Prefer "normal" error handling if possible. For more details read [Why does Go not have exceptions?](http://golang.org/doc/faq#exceptions), and blog posts [Error handling and Go](http://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go) and [Defer, Panic, and Recover](http://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover).

Answer (score 0):

for something more, "panic" could only be "recover" within the same routine, it couldn't be recovered outside.

https://play.golang.org/p/e7-3SU2Cvss